# How to tell the Activity type when loading a persisted workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

Question:

Is there an easy way to find out what Activity Type was used to create a workflow?

Background:

I am writing my own `WorkflowApplication` based Windows Workflow 4 hosting engine and I am having some issues trying to load persisted workflows out of the database.  I am using the `WorkflowApplication.Load(Guid)` method to start the workflow, but this requires me to already create the `WorkflowApplication`.

Looking at the `SqlWorkflowInstanceStore` databases, I don't see the type name stored anywhere and I don't see an easy to to associate it short of making another table myself just to store that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using workflow services the relative URL is used to determine if a WorkflowServiceHost owns the workflow instance, this is done through the ServiceDeploymentsTable table in the database. There is no similar mechanism when you are using a WorkflowApplication so you have to roll your own.

One thing you could do is use property promotion to store the type in the InstancePromotedPropertiesTable. It will save you from creating a new table but is hardly an ideal way of solving the problem.

Comment: I just wanted to say that your website has been amazingly useful for me while I work on this project.  It seems to be the only place to find deeper information on WF4.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have 2 options for doing that, neither of them optimal:

- You could use promoted properties as Maurice already suggested to store the info in the InstancePromotedPropertiesTable and avoid having to create your own table. There's a nice article [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364726.aspx).
- if you decide to create your own table, I'd suggest you implement a [PersistenceIOParticipant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.persistence.persistenceioparticipant.aspx). Check out [the sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd764467.aspx), you could always store the type name or your XAML instead of the path.

Comment: Awesome contribution on the `PersistenceIOParticipant`!